# How to sample a perfect partition uniformly at random?

Tags: partitions, sampling

I would like to sample $n$ integers (of some fixed length, say $k$ bits) uniformly at random, and have them partitioned into two sets of equal sum. Since finding such a perfect partition (even if it exists) is NP-hard, I would like to sample them in advance such that they are partitioned into two sets of equal sum. A naive algorithm is:

- Sample some integers for the first set; let $S$ be their sum.
- Sample some integers for the second set, until their sum exceeds $S$; then stop and truncate the last integer sampled so that the sum in the second set is exactly $S$.

The problem is that it does not guarantee that the integers are sampled uniformly at random.

Is it possible to sample two sets with an equal sum, such that each $k$-bit integer has the same chance of being chosen?

Comment: How do you define sampling an **integer** uniformly? are they bounded? if not, what probability distribution do you want from them?

Comment: Yes, they are bounded to $k$ bits, as I wrote in the first paragraph.

Comment: The naive way to sample from the set $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n) \in [m]^{2n} : \sum_i x_i = \sum_i y_i \}$ is rejection sampling: sample tuples without the condition, until it holds. My guess is that the expected number of repeats is roughly the standard deviation, which in this case is $O(\sqrt{nm}) = O(\sqrt{n} 2^{k/2})$.

Comment: Can you explain what distribution you are trying to sample from?

Comment: Given $S$, you can sample uniformly from $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in [m]^n : \sum_i x_i = S\}$ iteratively: for each value of $x_1$, count the number of solutions with that value, use this to sample $x_1$, and continue. You can count (or estimate) the number of solutions in various ways, resulting in various running times.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus do you mean that I should compute the marginal distribution of $x_1$ and sample from that, and then compute the marginal distribution of $x_2$ given the chosen $x_1$ and sample from that, etc.? (so $x_n$ will be deterministic?)

Comment: Yes, this is one approach. It's not necessarily feasible to carry out exactly.

Comment: So for the original problem - sampling uniformly at random from the pairs of subsets with an equal sum - I should first choose the sum by its marginal distribution, and then choose two subsets by the above algorithm?

Comment: I'm confused, is $n$ fixed (from "Sample some integers for the second set, until their sum exceeds $S$" it seems not to be the case)? If yes, then a variation of your approach + @YuvalFilmus's suggestion should be OK: "sample $n-1$ numbers, compute $x_n$, check that $x_n$ is in $[0, 2^k - 1]$, otherwise resample"

Comment: @Dmitry That wouldn't necessarily result in a uniform distribution.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, sorry, you are right.  But in the scheme I proposed the probabilities for different values of $x_n$ are not too far apart from each other (I tested it and for $n=4$ the difference between probabilities is at most a factor of $1.5$, and it becomes less as $n$ increases), and we can compute the probabilities. Do you know if it possible to modify rejection sampling to fix the probabilities (e.g. we when an $x_n$ with a higher probability is sampled, we reject it with some probability)?